# Image format not supported PyGame

Tags: python, pygame, python-3.10

So, I'm trying to change the PyGame icon for a game I am working on. Whenever I run the code, it hits me with `pygame.error: Unsupported image format`

The pygame window also opens and closes with the code under # Setting the game icon, and it did not do that when I did not have those lines in the code.

I've searched for a good answer, but I can't find a good one. If anyone's got any suggestions I would appreciate them.

I am programming on Visual Studio Code with Python 3.10

Here is my code:

```
import time
import pygame

# Initializes Pygame
pygame.init()

# Game Screen Variables
background_colour = (255,255,255)


# Sets up the playscreen
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1100,750),0,32)
pygame.display.set_caption("Dusco's Game")
screen.fill(background_colour)
pygame.display.flip()

# Setting the game icon
img = pygame.image.load('gameicon.png')
pygame.display.set_icon(img)


# Game Loop
running = True
while running:
  for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
      running = False

pygame.quit ()
```

Comment: Why do you post all the code? The problem is not with your code, but with your system. Anyway, in which line of your code do you get the error. Always post the complete error trace.

Comment: I get the error in this line:

```img = pygame.image.load('gameicon.png')```

I'm new to PyGame so I'm not too sure whether it is my code or my system.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your code. The problem is with your system. Your system cannot deal with this PNG file.

Comment: I understand, is there a way to resolve the issue?

Comment: The file may be damaged, try a different one. Anyway, this is not a coding problem so you are wrong here. Other than that, no one can help you without knowing your system. (OS, installed versions of python, pygame)

Comment: Maybe you can convert picture manually to the format that it wants (jpg or ico), or read it with openCV and convert to the format that pygame lib wants it.

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: `pygame` uses C/C++ library `SDL` and it may need other C/C++ libraries to read images. Maybe you need to install some library for `png` - maybe `libpng`. Because it is C/C++ library, not Python module, so you have to download and install it on your own. You may need to check web page for `SDL` for more information.

Comment: OR maybe problem is that `Python 3.10` is very new version and some modules may not be ready to work with this version and it is better wait few month and use `3.9` or even `3.8`

Comment: Pygame comes with SDL_Image and libpng already, this error is strange. I think the problem must be with the image. If it is actually a different format just renamed to png, that would break. If pygame was installed in a strange way (built from source improperly, not from pip) then it may not contain png loading functionality, but all pygame installations have bitmap loading guaranteed, so they could also try a .bmp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that it is a `PNG` and that you do the path so since it is erroring try this:

```
img = pygame.image.load('c:/users/USERNAME/PATH_TO_IMAGE/gameicon.png')
```